# How to share debug.keystore?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-signin, android-keystore

I am onboard new team member so can work together on Flutter mobile app. We are use Firebase so we need use same Android `debug.keystore` for debug build. How we can share this or check into GitHub so future team member can also use? How I can modify Flutter to use this key for debug signing?

Or maybe is better way for do this?

Thanks!

Comment: You can share it like you would any file that needs to be kept out of public view.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks for reply! To confirm, this is correct way to handle debug app signing for team in Firebase? Because otherwise Firebase auth is not work with different debug signing key.

Comment: The correct way is the one that works for your team. They don't need to all share the same keystore, but the project would need to be configured to allow everyone's keystore.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks for reply! Are you mean can also add more SHA fingerprint to project? There is any Firebase docs for explain this?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to share the file and instead add everyone's debug key to the project, use the "Add fingerprint" button in the console in the configuration for the app.